# how to eliminate pTex tags from a pdf file generated with pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, privacy

pdflatex generates pdf with properties (tags) embedded in the pdf file like author, subject, keywords and more. Most of them are settable with hyperref package, but some are not. My problem is with the "location" (localização in portuguese) that shows the full path to the file (file://home/..../file.pdf). I'd like to suppress this information from the pdf file. I tried pdfprivacy package but it did not work, as the exiftool program (the tag does not appear as a tag).

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Show a small complete example that can be used for tests.

Comment: The location is a property of your current, local copy of the file. It is not embedded in the document itself, the filesystem provides the information. If you copy the file somewhere else (put it on a usb stick, send it by mail, upload it somewhere) then the location information is not copied - a viewer will show the new location wherever the file is opened.

Comment: Thanks! I copied it to other directory, and the value changed as you said.